# Create JUnit for private method with ContextRefreshedEvent argument

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit

I want to create a JUnit test for this private method:

```
@Component
public class ReportingProcessor {

    @EventListener
    private void collectEnvironmentData(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
    }
}
```

I tried this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ReportingTest {

    @Bean
    ServletWebServerFactory servletWebServerFactory() {
        return new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
    }

    @Test
    public void reportingTest() throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {


        GenericApplicationContext parent = new GenericApplicationContext();
        parent.refresh();
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Configuration.class).parent(parent).run();
        ContextRefreshedEvent refreshEvent = new ContextRefreshedEvent(context);        

        ReportingProcessor instance = new ReportingProcessor();

        Method m = ReportingProcessor.class.getDeclaredMethod("collectEnvironmentData", ContextRefreshedEvent.class);
        m.setAccessible(true);
        m.invoke(instance, refreshEvent);               
    }
}
```

But I get exception: `Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.`

What is the proper way to implement a mocked object for ContextRefreshedEvent?

Comment: Creating a test for a private method is a (very) bad practice. Try to refactor your code so you can test it or byproducts that it will affect, by using mocks

Comment: Can you show me how to mock this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a whole lot of debate/insights on why you should not/avoid writing unit tests for private methods. Have a look at this SO question that should help you decide and provide more insights - [How do I test a private function or a class that has private methods, fields or inner classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571/how-do-i-test-a-private-function-or-a-class-that-has-private-methods-fields-or)

But, if you want to achieve what you have posted anyway; let me break down a few things which are failing the test.

1. Spring Boot tests need to be annotated with `@SpringBootTest` (if using JUnit 5) and additionally with `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` if you are using JUnit 4
2. You should not be creating an instance of your class with the `new` operator in the test, let the Test context automatically loads it using `@Autowired` or any other similar mechanism to inject the class.
3. To mock your input parameter and to invoke the private method you can use `Powermockito` library. Please note that if your scenario would not have required invoking a private method then `mockito` library should be enough for almost all mocking scenarios.

Below is the test that should work:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class ReportingProcessorTest {

    @Autowired
    ReportingProcessor reportingProcessor;

    @Test
    public void reportingTest() throws Exception {

        ContextRefreshedEvent contextRefreshedEvent = PowerMockito.mock(ContextRefreshedEvent.class);
        Whitebox.invokeMethod(reportingProcessor, "collectEnvironmentData", contextRefreshedEvent);

    }
}
```

Comment: I get `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest(classes=...) with your test`

Comment: yeah, that's a pretty common error, it occurs when your spring boot test is unable to find either a class that is of type SpringBootApplication or configuration class annotated by @Config, basically, it needs to load the context and needs a location of one of these, more - https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.0.M3/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-detecting-config

Comment: Well, I can't find a solution. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: your spring boot project is not correctly setup, I will suggest creating a new project from https://start.spring.io/ just to understand what could be wrong with your project structure